# Excel: can I set the label distance in x-axis based on its label number?

Tags: excel, figure

I have a graph in Excel like below. For the X-axis, the distance between 50 and 100 is the same as that between 100 and 200. Can I ask if I can set it based on the number? That is, the distance between 50 and 100, is half of that between 100 and 200.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can use a scatter plot rather than a line chart. The result looks something like this:

[image]

To generate the plot, I selected the whole data block and did `Insert > Scatter` with the subtype consisting of markers with straight-line segments. I don't know of any way to not show horizontal labels at 50, 100, 200 without doing things like 150, but at least the spacing is right. Obviously, the size, style, and color of the markers and lines are easy to tweak, as is the number and spacing of the horizontal grid lines.